# Spacer Breaks Button Appearance, Button Still Toggles

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created an HStack that houses a collection of buttons that change appearance when selected and deselected. Only one button can be selected at a time. When adding a Spacer() between items, the button toggle works, however the appearance no longer changes, even though the index selected is changing as it's supposed to.

```
struct GenericFilterButton: View {
    var category: String
    var textColor: Color
    var buttonColor: Color
    var body: some View {
        Text(category)
            .font(.custom("Avenir Heavy", size: 14))
            .foregroundColor(textColor)
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .padding(.horizontal, 14)
            .background(buttonColor)
            .cornerRadius(50)
            .lineLimit(1)
    }
}

struct FilterViewCompletionPercent: View {
    var completionPercent = ["Any", "25%", "50%", "75%", "100%"]
    @State var percentSelected = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text("Completion")
                .font(.custom("Avenir Heavy", size: 18))
                .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                ForEach(0..<completionPercent.count) { i in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.percentSelected = i
                        print(self.percentSelected)
                    }) {
                        GenericFilterButton(category: self.completionPercent[i], textColor: self.percentSelected == i ? Color.white : Color.black.opacity(0.5), buttonColor: self.percentSelected == i ? Color.blue : Color.white.opacity(0.0))
                    }
                    if i != 4 {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 20)
            Divider()
                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.1))
        }.padding(.horizontal, 25)
            .padding(.top, 30)
    }
}
```

Why may this be happening? I can't seem to think of a plausible reason why adding a Spacer() between items doesn't work, but when adding a Spacer() without the if statement does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic content of `ForEach` should be *single* view, so embed your Button-Spacer pair into another `HStack`.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
HStack(alignment: .center) {
    ForEach(0..<completionPercent.count, id: \.self) { i in
        HStack {                       // << this one !!
            Button(action: {
                self.percentSelected = i
                print(self.percentSelected)
            }) {
                GenericFilterButton(category: self.completionPercent[i], textColor: self.percentSelected == i ? Color.white : Color.black.opacity(0.5), buttonColor: self.percentSelected == i ? Color.blue : Color.white.opacity(0.0))
            }
            if i != 4 {
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}.padding(.bottom, 20)
```